# Overload resolution and arrays: which function should be called?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, c++11, overload-resolution

Consider the following program:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

void f(char const*&&)      { std::puts("char const*&&");      } // (1)
void f(char const* const&) { std::puts("char const* const&"); } // (2)

template <std::size_t N>
void f(char const (&)[N])  { std::puts("char const(&)[N]");   } // (3)

int main()
{
    const char data[] = "a";
    f(data);
}
```

**Which `f` should be called?  Why?**

The latest released versions of three compilers disagree on the answer to this question:

- **(1)** is called when the program is compiled using **g++ 4.5.2**
- **(2)** is called when the program is compiled using **Visual C++ 2010 SP1**
- **(3)** is called when the program is compiled using **Clang 3.0 (trunk 127530)**

Have the overload resolution rules changed substantially in different C++0x drafts?  Or, are two of these compilers really just completely wrong?  Which overload is the correct overload to be selected per the latest C++0x draft?

Comment: I tried reading Clause 13 ("Overloading") of the latest C++0x draft, N3242, but that gave me a headache.

Comment: I'm pretty sure gcc is doing it wrong.  Even when all three candidates are templates, gcc still prefers the conversion-to-pointer over the exact-match array reference.  http://ideone.com/7UXag

Comment: @Ben:  I would have agreed with you before I read Clause 13:  in the table, the Array-to-pointer conversion is ranked as an Exact Match, which would mean that (2) is the correct selection here since (3) is a template, but that would also mean that in your example, where all three overloads are templates, there should be an ambiguity between at least (2) and (3).  :-(

Comment: Not an answer, but I think (2) is an exact match, isn't it?

Comment: @James: And that's not even the right section, AFAICT.  Since one of the candidates is a template function, section 14.8.3 governs.

Comment: @James: Identity trumps exact match: 13.3.3.2: "Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence
S2 if
—  S1 is a proper subsequence of  S2 (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form
deﬁned by 13.3.3.1.1, excluding any Lvalue Transformation; the identity conversion sequence is
considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence)"

Comment: 13.3.3.1.4: "When a parameter of reference type binds directly (8.5.3) to an argument expression, the implicit conversion
sequence is the identity conversion"

Comment: @Ben:  However, 14.8.3/1 says, "The synthesized declarations are treated like any other functions in the remainder of overload resolution, except as explicitly noted in 13.3.3."  The only other contents of 14.8.3 are examples, really, unless I've missed something.

Comment: @Ben:  Ah.  That sentence (from 13.3.3.2) seems to be the one that I missed.  I shall go back and read through that again.

Comment: @James: I'm trying to collect those clauses here, using a wiki answer

Comment: Amazed how you found a scenario where all three gave different answers.

Comment: @DeadMG: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346836/c0x-distinguishing-rvalue-pointers/5346875#5346875

Comment: Oh hey look, I'm using an old draft :(  Doesn't look like any of these paragraphs changed, however.

Comment: @Ben:  Oh, yeah:  N3242 was just released in the pre-Madrid mailing.  I haven't seen many major changes in it ("template aliases" are now "alias templates," if that counts as major :-D).  Hopefully we'll have an FDIS next month.

Comment: reported to clang: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9507

Comment: The Clang bug was closed with a resolution of "fixed" on June 5, build 132660.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, the conversion sequence of all three is the same, except that for the first two, there is an lvalue transformation (lvalue to rvalue conversion), which however is not used in ordering conversion sequences. All three are exact matches (the function template specialization has parameter type `char const(&)[2]`).

If you iterate over the rules at `13.3.3.2p3`, you stop at this paragraph

> S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared without a ref-qualifier, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and S2 binds an lvalue reference.

A conversion sequence cannot be formed if it requires binding an rvalue reference to an lvalue, the spec says at 13.3.3.1.4p3. If you look at how reference binding works at 8.5.3p5 last bullet, it will create a temporary (I think they meant *rvalue* temporary) of type `char const*` from the array lvalue and bind the reference to that temporary. Therefor, I think `(1)` is better than `(2)`. Same holds for `(1)` against `(3)`, although we wouldn't need this because `(3)` is a template so in a tie, we would choose `(1)` again.

In `n3225`, they changed the reference binding rules so that rvalue references can bind to initializer expressions that are lvalues, as long as the reference will be bound to an rvalue (possibly created by converting the initializer properly before). This could influence the handling by Visual C++, which may not be up to date here.

I'm not sure about clang. Even if it would ignore `(1)`, then it would end up in a tie between `(2)` and `(3)`, and would need to choose `(2)` because it's a non-template.

---

I think that 8.5.3p5 last bullet is confusing because it says "Otherwise a temporary of type ..". It's not clear whether the temporary is regarded as an lvalue or as an rvalue by 13.3.3.1.4p3, which means I'm not sure how the following should really behave according to the exact words of the spec

```
void f(int &);
void f(int &&);

int main() {
  int n = 0;
  f(n);
}
```

If we assume the temporary is treated as an rvalue by clause 13, then we bind an rvalue ref to an rvalue in the second function and an lvalue in the first. Therefor, we will choose the second function and then get a diagnostic by 8.5.3p5 last bullet because `T1` and `T2` are reference-related. If we assume the temporary is treated as an lvalue by clause 13, then the following would not work

```
void f(int &&);
int main() {
  f(0);
}
```

Because we would bind an rvalue ref to an lvalue which by clause 13 will make the function non-viable. And if we interpret "binding an rvalue ref to an lvalue" to refer to the initializer expression instead of the final expression bound to, we won't accept the following

```
void f(float &&);
int main() {
  int n = 0;
  f(n);
}
```

This however is valid as of n3225. So there seems to be some confusion - I sent a DR to the committee about this.

Comment: Very interesting.  It's a shame that the array-to-pointer conversion is still an exact match.  It would be nice to be able to match arrays specifically (on the other hand, the only time I've ever wanted to do this was in answering questions here, so... maybe it's not so useful :-P).  Thanks a lot for the analysis and for the DR and Clang bug reports.  I'll follow up with Visual C++ to see what they think (since the rule changed in N3225, that does explain why Visual C++'s behavior is different).

Answer (score 4):

I claim that #3 is the function chosen by a conforming compiler.

(1) is better than (2) because "Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared without a ref-qualiﬁer, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and S2 binds an lvalue reference."

(3) is better than both (1) and (2) because it is an identity conversion (the others are exact match conversions) and "Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if S1 is a proper subsequence of S2 (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form defined by 13.3.3.1.1, excluding any Lvalue Transformation; the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence)"

Template vs non-template is only considered when neither conversion is better "or, if not that..."

oddly enough though, Comeau prefers (2) over (3).  This test case fails to compile:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

// (1) removed because Comeau doesn't support rvalue-references yet
char f(char const* const&) { std::puts("char const* const&"); return 0; } // (2)

template <std::size_t N>
int f(char const (&)[N])  { std::puts("char const(&)[N]"); return 0; } // (3)

int main()
{
    const char data[] = "a";
    switch (0) {
       case sizeof(char):
           break;
       case sizeof(f(data)):
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124153/discussion-on-answer-by-ben-voigt-overload-resolution-and-arrays-which-function).

Answer (score 2):

This is a community wiki answer for collecting snippets from the standard (draft 3225).

**section 13.3.3 "Best viable function" `[over.match.best]`**

1. Deﬁne ICSi(F) as follows:

   - if `F` is a static member function, ICS1(F) is deﬁned such that ICS1(F) is neither better nor worse than
     ICS1(G) for any function `G`, and, symmetrically, ICS1(G) is neither better nor worse than ICS1(F); otherwise,
   - let ICSi(F) denote the implicit conversion sequence that converts the i-th argument in the list to the
     type of the i-th parameter of viable function `F`. 13.3.3.1 deﬁnes the implicit conversion sequences and
     13.3.3.2 deﬁnes what it means for one implicit conversion sequence to be a better conversion sequence or worse conversion sequence than another.

   Given these deﬁnitions, a viable function `F1` is deﬁned to be a better function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments *i*, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then

   - for some argument *j*, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICSj(F2)

   or, if not that,

   - the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion (see 8.5,  13.3.1.5,  and 13.3.1.6) and the standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F1` to the destination type (i.e., the type of the entity being initialized) is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F2` to the destination type

   or, if not that,

   - `F1` is a non-template function and `F2` is a function template specialization

   or, if not that,

   - `F1` and `F2` are function template specializations, and the function template for `F1` is more specialized
     than the template for `F2` according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.6.2.
2. If there is exactly one viable function that is a better function than all other viable functions, then it is the one selected by overload resolution; otherwise the call is ill-formed.

**section 13.3.3.1.4 "Reference binding" `[over.ics.ref]`**

1. When a parameter of reference type binds directly (8.5.3) to an argument expression, the implicit conversion
   sequence is the identity conversion, unless the argument expression has a type that is a derived class of the
   parameter type, in which case the implicit conversion sequence is a derived-to-base conversion  (13.3.3.1).  If the parameter binds directly to the result of applying a conversion function to the
   argument expression, the implicit conversion sequence is a user-deﬁned conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.2), with the second standard conversion sequence either an identity conversion or, if the conversion function
   returns an entity of a type that is a derived class of the parameter type, a derived-to-base Conversion.
2. When a parameter of reference type is not bound directly to an argument expression, the conversion sequence
   is the one required to convert the argument expression to the underlying type of the reference according
   to 13.3.3.1.   Conceptually,  this conversion sequence corresponds to copy-initializing a temporary of the
   underlying type with the argument expression.  Any diﬀerence in top-level cv-qualiﬁcation is subsumed by
   the initialization itself and does not constitute a conversion.

**section 13.3.3.2 "Ranking implicit conversion sequences" `[over.ics.rank]`**

1. 13.3.3.2 deﬁnes a partial ordering of implicit conversion sequences based on the relationships better conversion
   sequence and better conversion. If an implicit conversion sequence `S1` is deﬁned by these rules to be a better
   conversion sequence than `S2`, then it is also the case that `S2` is a worse conversion sequence than `S1`.  If
   conversion sequence `S1` is neither better than nor worse than conversion sequence `S2`, `S1` and `S2` are said to
   be indistinguishable conversion sequences.
2. When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as deﬁned in 13.3.3.1)

   - a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence, and
   - a user-deﬁned conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.2) is a better conversion sequence than an ellipsis conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.3).
3. Two implicit conversion sequences of the same form are indistinguishable conversion sequences unless one of
   the following rules applies:

   - Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence `S2` if

     - S1 is a proper subsequence of  S2 (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form defined by 13.3.3.1.1, excluding any Lvalue Transformation; the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence)

     or, if not that,

     - the rank of `S1` is better than the rank of `S2`, or `S1` and `S2` have the same rank and are distinguishable by the rules in the paragraph below

     or, if not that,

     - `S1` and `S2` differ only in their qualification conversion and yield similar types `T1` and `T2` (4.4), respectively, and the cv-qualification signature of type `T1` is a proper subset of the cv-qualification signature of type `T2`.

     or, if not that,

     - `S1` and `S2` are reference bindings (8.5.3) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a
       non-static member function declared without a ref-qualiﬁer, and `S1` binds an rvalue reference to
       an rvalue and `S2` binds an lvalue reference.