# no matching function for call to function template

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<class T, T i> void f(int[10][i]) { };

int main() {
   int a[10][30];
   f(a);
}
```

Why does `f(a)` fail?

http://ideone.com/Rkc1Z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f(a)` fails because a template type argument cannot be deduced from the type of a non-type argument. In this case the compiler cannot deduce the type of the template parameter `T`.

Try calling it as `f<int>(a);`

Comment: Mmm suboptimal. It took some tinkering (i.e. reading up), but [there is a good way to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771314/no-matching-function-for-call-to-function-template/5771415#5771415). (_The second template param actually should never have been of type T_)

Comment: Why a downvote? The question asked is why `f(a)` fails and my post manages to answer that.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
template<class T, T i> void f(T[10][i]) { }; // note the 'T'

int main() {
   int a[10][30];
   f(a);
}
```

.. this enables the compiler to deduce the type of `T`, which is totally impossible in your sample (because `T` is not used at all).

http://ideone.com/gyQqI

Answer (score 1):

```
template< std::size_t N > void f(int (&arr)[10][N])
{
}

int main() {
   int a[10][30];
   f(a);
}
```

This one works (http://codepad.org/iXeqanLJ)

---

Useful backgrounder: [Overload resolution and arrays: which function should be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347444/overload-resolution-and-arrays-which-function-should-be-called)