# Force one overload to be attempted first, before falling back on another

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

As one example of a broader problem, given these two overloads, you might think that the array version would take priority when an array is passed:

```
template <size_t N>
void bar(const char (&)[N]) { 
    std::cout << "array, size=" << N-1 << std::endl;
}
void bar(const char *s)  { 
    std::cout << "raw, size=" << strlen(s) << std::endl;
}
```

but when passing an array (a string literal is an array), `bar("hello")`, the latter version (the pointer version) will be called instead.

This particular case [has been discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243371/why-does-pointer-decay-take-priority-over-a-deduced-template/28243509?noredirect=1#comment44849945_28243509) on SO, and the answer is interesting. But there is a general question here. I want to force the compiler to prefer one overload, and to only abandon that overload only when all legal attempts to call it have failed.

Let's rename them to `bar1` and `bar2` for clarity:

```
template <size_t N>
void bar1(const char (&)[N]) { 
    std::cout << "array, size=" << N-1 << std::endl;
}
void bar2(const char *s)  { 
    std::cout << "raw, size=" << strlen(s) << std::endl;
}
```

Without changing those any further, can we write something like this:

```
template<typename ...Args>
auto try_bar1_then_bar2(Args&& ...args) -> ??? { 
    ... will first attempt to perfect forward to bar1 ...
    ... only if bar1 cannot be called, fallback to bar2 ...
}
```

I've used some C++11 in this question, with && for perfect forwarding, but I guess the general question applies to earlier C++ also. Is there a simple, general, way to force a reordering of the overload priority? When a set of functions (with different names?) are (barely) callable, how to control exactly what order they are attempted in?

Answer (score 2):

Some Expression SFINAE:

```
template<typename ...Args>
auto try_bar1_then_bar2_IMPL(int, Args&& ...args) -> decltype( bar1(forward<Args>(args)...) ) { 
    cout << "Yes, we can call bar1" << endl;
    return bar1(forward<Args>(args)...);
}
template<typename ...Args>
auto try_bar1_then_bar2_IMPL(char, Args&& ...args) -> void { 
    cout << "No, can't call bar1, calling bar2 instead." << endl;
    return bar2(forward<Args>(args)...);
}
template<typename ...Args>
auto try_bar1_then_bar2(Args&& ...args) -> decltype( try_bar1_then_bar2_IMPL(0, forward<Args>(args)...) ) { 
    return try_bar1_then_bar2_IMPL(0, forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

When `bar1` cannot be called, the first overload of `try_bar1_then_bar2_IMPL` is invalid because the `decltype` in the return type fails. But if `bar1` can be called, then both are valid (and are perfectly matched, I think). I've therefore added a dummy parameter in front, an `int` or `char`, which tie breaks in favour of the call to `bar1`.

This is called like so:

```
try_bar1_then_bar2("hello");  // array, calls array version
try_bar1_then_bar2(+"hello"); // + converts to a pointer, therefore
                                 // this calls the pointer ('raw') version.
```

Comment: (Answering own question here). I'm not very good at this overload resolution and tie-breaking. Is my answer correct in general? Any feedback welcome!

Comment: @PiotrS. Thanks, I removed my use of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` also. I find it very useful in debugging, but it's not standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the arguments with a template to get the desired overloaded function:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Wrap
{
    const T& value;

    Wrap(const T& value)
    : value(value)
    {}
};

template <typename T>
inline Wrap<T> wrap(const T& value) {
    return Wrap<T>(value);
}


template <size_t N>
void bar(const Wrap<char[N]>&) {
    std::cout << "array, size=" << N-1 << std::endl;
}

void bar(const Wrap<const char *>& s)  {
    std::cout << "raw, size=" << strlen(s.value) << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void bar(const T& value) {
    bar(wrap(value));
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const char a[] ="hello";
    const char* s ="hello";
    bar(a);
    bar(s);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with non-const values. E.g. `char * s; bar(s)`. I guess the general point is that I don't want to look only for perfect matches of arguments. There is always scope for conversions of various kinds. I want `bar1` to have priority and only after the compiler has established that `bar1` cannot be called, regardless of conversions, should it then move to `bar2`. And finally, relevant to your answer, if `bar1` is rejected, I want the compiler to try its best to call `bar2`. I don't want `bar2` to fail just because it doesn't notice that it can convert `char*` to `const char *`.