# Is it possible to extract array size from a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

If this is a duplicate I apologize. I looked around and found similar issues but nothing exactly like this.

If I instantiate a template like so...

```
MyClass<int[10]> c;
```

**How can I write the template to get access to both the type and the array size?** I've tried everything I can think of and I can't get it.

I was inspired by the std::function template which lets you use similar syntax to the function prototype, like...

```
std::function<int(MyClass&)> myfunc;
```

So I thought it would be nice to have something similar for the array and its size. I can use any of the newest c++ features (c++ 11/14).

Comment: Why don't you use `std::array<int, 10>`? It's awesome and you should use it ;-)

Comment: @stefan: Well, I'm trying to add some contextual syntactic sugar to a class of mine. It has nothing to do with me using actual arrays.

Comment: Is that syntax the only valid use of your class, or is it a special case ?

Comment: you should take care of some pitfalls when you do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243371/why-does-pointer-decay-take-priority-over-a-deduced-template

Comment: Instead of writing your own metafunctions to extract the element type and array size, you could use `std::extent` and `std::remove_extent`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add a partial specialization which looks like this:

```
template <typename T, ptrdiff_t N>
class MyClass<T[N]>
{
};
```

Here's a [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b96a37b65ec2f8ae).

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you. I was having such a hard time with the syntax I couldn't get anything working.

Comment: @Pradhan: `int` instead of `size_t` may *look* like poor style to some poor soul who is sufficiently unsure that he (it's inevitably a he) doesn't want to state or stand by his, well, impression. That said, at least some old versions of g++ had a bug which effectively required you to use `size_t`. I would use a size type defined as `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks! Updated the answer, but I am unable to find the relevant gcc bug report.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class Arr>
struct array_size {};
template<class T, size_t N>
struct array_size<T[N]>:std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>{};
template<class Arr>
struct array_element {};
template<class Arr>
using array_element_t = typename array_element<Arr>::type;
template<class T, size_t N>
struct array_element<T[N]>{using type=T;};
```

now you can `array_size<ArrType>{}` and `array_element_t<ArrType>` without unpacking the type.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct deduce
{
};

template <typename T>
struct deduce<T,
  typename ::std::enable_if<
    ::std::is_array<T>{}
  >::type
>
{
  using value_type =
    typename ::std::decay<decltype(::std::declval<T>()[0])>::type;

  static constexpr auto size = sizeof(T) / sizeof(value_type);
};
```

Comment: Isn't this completely overkill ?

Comment: Yeah, just for some variety.

Comment: "Overkill for variety". I like that :p

Comment: Nice. While it is too complicated, it has some concepts I would like to learn more about. I will use this to advance my template skills. Thanks.

Comment: What about just `std::extent`?

Comment: @Columbo Yeah, would be prettier.