# Odd behavior of different compilers with references to array of unknown bound

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang++, c++17

**Case 1**

The following code produces drastically different results in MSVC and GCC:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo(const T&) {
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    std::cout << "foo(const T&): " << __FUNCDNAME__ << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
#endif
}

void foo(const char*) {
    std::cout << "foo(const char*)" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    extern char s[];
    foo(s);
}

char s[] = "abc";
```

MSVC 2013 Update 5, MSVC 2015 Update 1 (also tried Update 2 on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net with the same result):

```
foo(const char*)
```

GCC 5.3.0, Clang 3.7.0 ([DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f8cab913bb9a304)):

```
void foo(const T&) [with T = char []]
```

**Case 2**

Now let's remove the templates:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(const char(&)[]) {
    std::cout << "foo(const char(&)[])" << std::endl;
}

void foo(const char*) {
    std::cout << "foo(const char*)" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    extern char s[];
    foo(s);
}

char s[] = "abc";
```

MSVC produces error:

```
error C2668: 'foo' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
could be 'void foo(const char *)'
or       'void foo(const char (&)[])'
```

GCC produces another error (with both `-std=c++14` and `-std=c++1z`):

```
main.cpp:3:29: error: parameter '<anonymous>' includes reference to array of unknown bound 'const char []'
     void foo(const char(&)[]) {
```

And Clang compiles with both `-std=c++14` and `-std=c++1z` and outputs:

```
foo(const char(&)[])
```

---

For the first case, in my opininon with C++14 the specialization `void foo(const T&) [with T = char []]` shouldn't have been produced in the first place, so MSVC is right. But in C++1z GCC and Clang are right.

For the second case, I think with C++14 GCC is right and with C++1z Clang is right.

(The important difference between C++14 and C++1z here is [CWG 393](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#393))

---

So the questions are, which compiler is right in the first and the second cases in C++14 (N4140) and C++1z (N4567)?

And another question, which compiler(s), if any, should I file a bug for?

Comment: `const char(&)[]` ???

Comment: If you make `s` a `const char[]`, you will get similar error messages in all three compilers

Comment: @melak47 that's the point, qualification conversion to `const` is important here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const char(&)[]` is a valid parameter as of CWG 393; I filed the corresponding [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69316)  for GCC just a week ago.

As for which of VC++ and Clang is correct, first see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243371/why-does-pointer-decay-take-priority-over-a-deduced-template/28243509#28243509); MSVC *would* be correct if `s` was declared `const`. However, because it wasn't, we have to perform both an array-to-pointer and **qualification conversion** in the `char const*` case - which makes the other SCS a subsequence of this one (Qualification Adjustment, as opposed to Lvalue Transformation, is not ignored!), i.e. Clang is correct in both cases.

Comment: But qualification conversion is performed in both cases, and moreover, the conversions are different (`char*` -> `char const*` and `char(&)[]` -> `char const(&)[]`), so how can one sequence be a subsequence of another?

Comment: Qualification conversion solely happens for pointers. The array reference binds directly, and that's all that counts.