# Interface design: safety of overloaded function taking string and char array

Tags: c++, interface

Say we have a class that can write stuff to output

```
class Writer
{
public:
    int write(const std::string& str);
    int write(const char* str, int len);
    //...
};
```

I was fine with this, its flexible and all that, until I realized

```
char* buf = new char[n]; //not terminated with '\0'
//load up buf
Writer w;
w.write(buf);  //compiles!
```

That is a *really* nasty bug.

We can amend somewhat with some templating

```
class WriterV2
{
public:
    int write(const std::string& str);
    int write(const char* str, int len);
    template<typename... Args>
    int write(const char*, Args...)
    { static_assert(sizeof...(Args) < 0, "Incorrect arguments"); }
    //...
};
```

But this method has its problems

```
WriterV2 w;
w.write("The templating genius!"); //compile error
```

What do I do? What is a better design?

And before anyone asks, overloading for `const char (&)[N]` [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243371/why-does-pointer-decay-take-priority-over-a-deduced-template). It might be feasible to create a wrapper to do this, but that seems... overkill?

**EDIT** Adding a method `write(char*)` and emitting an error there is not ideal. When passing `buf` around through functions and all that, it might become `const char*`.

Comment: Why don't you just declare a method to handle this case but dont implement it?  int write(char* str);

Comment: Okay, but why must there be a distinction between the two types? Also, calling `w.write(buf);` will _always_ call `int Writer::write(const std::string& str);` If you want it to call `int Writer::write(const char* str, int len);`, then add a length parameter to your call.

Comment: Use std::vector as buffer.

Comment: @manni66 using `std::vector` as buffer is problematic on so many levels

Comment: @PasserBy as you have proven, not using std::vector is also problematic no so many levels ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ICS (Implicit Conversion Sequences)](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics) during overload resolution in C++ can produce surprising results as you've noticed, and also quite annoying..

You can provide necessary interfaces you need, then carefully employ templates to handle the *string literal* vs `const char*` fiasco by taking advantage of [partial ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005985/whats-the-partial-ordering-procedure-in-template-deduction) to `delete` the unwanted overload.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

class Writer
{
public:
    int write(std::string&&) { std::cout << "int write(std::string)\n"; return 0; }
    int write(const std::string&) { std::cout << "int write(const std::string& str)\n"; return 0; }
    int write(const char*, int){ std::cout << "int write(const char* str, int len)\n"; return 0; }

    template<std::size_t N = 0, typename = std::enable_if_t<(N > 0)> >
    int write(const char (&)[N]) { std::cout << "int write(string-literal) " << N << " \n"; return 0; }


    template<typename T>
    int write(T&&) = delete;

};

int main(){
    char* buf = new char[30];
    const char* cbuf = buf;
    Writer w;

    //w.write(buf);                     //Fails! 
    //w.write(cbuf);                    //Fails! 
    w.write(buf, 30);                   //Ok!    int write(const char*, int);
    w.write(std::string("Haha"));       //Ok!    int write(std::string&&);
    w.write("This is cool");            //Ok!    int write(const char (&)[13]);
}
```

Prints:

```
int write(const char* str, int len)
int write(std::string)
int write(string-literal) 13
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e3ae9e5602c83ea)

---

Note that the solution above inherits a disadvantage of "overloading a function with an unconstrained *Forwarding Reference*". This means that all ICS to the argument type(s) of the viable functions in the overload set will be "deleted"

Comment: For completeness, can you add in that this has the downside of disabling *all* implicit conversions to `std::string`?

Comment: @PasserBy, added. Thanks!