# requirements for custom container type to use with views

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I start to play with `std::ranges` and want understand how views really work. So I try to write my own container and iterator type and want to use it in a view.

But something seems to be missing but the compiler only tells me that there is no `begin()` method inside the view but not why.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <ranges>

class MyFixedContainer;
class MyIterator
{
    MyFixedContainer* ptr;
    unsigned int offset;
public:
    MyIterator( MyFixedContainer* ptr_, unsigned int offset_ ): ptr{ ptr_},offset{offset_}{}

    bool operator==( MyIterator& other ) const
    {   
        return ( ptr == other.ptr )&& ( offset == other.offset );
    }   

    bool operator!=( MyIterator& other ) const
    {   
        return !(*this == other);
    }   

    MyIterator operator++()
    {   
        offset++;
        return *this;
    }   

    MyIterator operator++(int)
    {   
        MyIterator tmp = *this;
        offset++;
        return tmp;
    }   

    int operator*() const;
};

class MyFixedContainer
{
    std::array<int,4> arr={5,6,7,8};
public:
    auto begin() { return MyIterator{ this, 0 }; }
    auto end() { return MyIterator{ this, 4}; }

    int Get( int offset ) const
    {
        return arr[ offset ];
    }
};

int MyIterator::operator*() const
{
    return ptr->Get( offset );
}

int main()
{
    MyFixedContainer c;

    // Container type itself works:
    for ( int i: c )
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    // Try to use with std::ranges
    auto even = [] (int i) { return 0 == i % 2; };

    auto y = std::views::filter(c, even);
    auto b = y.begin(); // << error message
}
```

Compiles with

> main.cpp:90:16: error: 'struct std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptorClosurestd::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptor<_Callable::operator()<{MyFixedContainer&, main()::<lambda(int)>&}>::<lambda(_Range&&)> >' has no member named 'begin'
> 90 |     auto b = y.begin();

https://godbolt.org/z/doW76j

Comment: By compile your code (after add includes), the first message I get is `'MyFixedContainer' does not name a type` . https://wandbox.org/permlink/XUwpnVHerzhb9q1R

Comment: @ Klaus, I know, I just point out it would be better if we can simply copy&past&compile and get the same error.

Comment: Basically a dupe of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549185/what-are-the-rules-for-creating-your-own-pipeable-ranges-views-and-actions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MyIterator` does not model [`std::input_or_output_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_or_output_iterator) because:

- It needs to be default constructible.
- `std::iter_difference_t<MyIterator>` must be valid, and
- the pre-increment operator must return a reference.

`MyIterator` is not a [`std::sentinel_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/sentinel_for)`<MyIterator, MyIterator>` because its operators `==` and `!=` take references instead of `const` references.

`MyIterator` does not satisfy [`std::input_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_iterator), which requires `std::iter_value_t` to be valid.

Fixing all of the above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <ranges>

class MyFixedContainer;
class MyIterator
{
    MyFixedContainer* ptr;
    unsigned int offset;
public:
    using difference_type = int;
    using value_type = int;
    
    MyIterator() = default;
    
    MyIterator( MyFixedContainer* ptr_, unsigned int offset_ ): ptr{ ptr_},offset{offset_}{}

    bool operator==( MyIterator const & other ) const
    {   
        return ( ptr == other.ptr )&& ( offset == other.offset );
    }   

    bool operator!=( MyIterator const & other ) const
    {   
        return !(*this == other);
    }   

    MyIterator &operator++()
    {   
        offset++;
        return *this;
    }   

    MyIterator operator++(int)
    {   
        MyIterator tmp = *this;
        offset++;
        return tmp;
    }   

    int operator*() const;
};

class MyFixedContainer
{
    std::array<int,4> arr={5,6,7,8};
public:
    auto begin() { return MyIterator{ this, 0 }; }
    auto end()   { return MyIterator{ this, 4}; }

    int Get( int offset ) const
    {
        return arr[ offset ];
    }
};

int MyIterator::operator*() const
{
    return ptr->Get( offset );
}

int main()
{
    MyFixedContainer c;

    // Container type itself works:
    for ( int i: c )
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    // Try to use with std::ranges
    auto even = [] (int i) { return 0 == i % 2; };

    static_assert(std::input_or_output_iterator<MyIterator>);
    static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<MyFixedContainer>);
    
    auto y = c | std::views::filter(even);
    
    auto b = y.begin(); // << OK
}
```

The error messages are much clearer if you `static_assert` every concept that your container/iterator has to model.

Comment: "The error messages are much clearer if you static_assert"... But there my problem starts: Which concept must be fulfilled...? Now I got the answer from you and can handle it. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Klaus Oh it’s not that hard at all. Say that you want your container to be a `std::ranges::random_access_range`. You only need to have a look at what concepts it subsumes. Thanks to concepts (and the hard work of C. Carter and E. Niebler, among others), now the algorithms library is self-documenting. That’s a significant improvement over the previous status quo.

Comment: Why does `Iterator` need a default constructor? Wouldn't this then mean that you can't have an `Iterator` that takes a `Container&` as a parameter, instead of a `Container*`?