# Array-to-pointer conversion + rvalue-ref: Overload resolution difference GCC vs clang

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define FUNC() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }

void foo(char const*&&   ) FUNC() // A
void foo(char const(&)[4]) FUNC() // B

int main()
{
    foo("bar");
}
```

[Demo](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/cTT1PK)

When using an rvalue reference in the parameter type of the first overload (A), clang current master unambiguously chooses that overload A over B. GCC current master on the other hand complains about an ambiguity.

I'm quite surprised that the string literal, being an *lvalue of 4 `char const`* ([[expr.prim.literal]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.literal#1.sentence-3), [[lex.string]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.string#6.sentence-2)) should prefer the array-to-pointer conversion on overload A over the identity conversion on overload B.

Without the rvalue reference, that is `void foo(char const*)`, both GCC and clang reject the call as ambiguous. That's also something I don't fully understand, since I would have guessed that there's still an array-to-pointer conversion and therefore [[over.ics.rank]p3.2.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over#ics.rank-3.2.1) applies:

> - Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if
>
>   - (3.2.1) S1 is a proper subsequence of S2 (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form defined by [over.ics.scs], excluding
>     any Lvalue Transformation; the identity conversion sequence is
>     considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion
>     sequence) or, if not that,

What is going on in either case?

Comment: This issue looks familiar but I have no idea how to search SO for that...

Comment: Maybe clang looks at https://eel.is/c++draft/over#ics.rank-3.2.3 and says, well, the decayed string literal is an rvalue...?

Comment: _Without the rvalue reference, that is void foo(char const*), both GCC and clang reject the call as ambiguous. That's also something I don't fully understand_ [CWG1789](http://wg21.link/cwg1789)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116173/overload-resolution-between-lvalue-reference-and-rvalue-reference related

Answer (score 3):

<sub>*(This is only a partial answer, covering the second case)*</sub>

> What is going on in either case?

Regarding the second case, as to why the following overloads

```
void foo(char const*     ) FUNC() // A
void foo(char const(&)[4]) FUNC() // B
```

yields ambiguous overloads (for both Clang and GCC); [[over.ics.rank]/3.2.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.1) may seem to favour B, being an identity conversion, over A, requiring an *array-to-pointer conversion* which in turn is in the *conversion category* of *Lvalue Transformation*:

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if
>
> - (3.2.1) S1 is a proper subsequence of S2 (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form defined by [over.ics.scs], **excluding any Lvalue Transformation**; *the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence*) or, if not that,
> - [...]

However, as I interpret the **first emphasized** segment above, Lvalue Transformation:s are excluded from both sequences S1 and S2 when applying [over.ics.rank]/3.2.1, and the *second emphasized* segment applies only after this exclusion has been applied.

---

As pointed out [in a comment by @LanguageLawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65705233/array-to-pointer-conversion-rvalue-ref-overload-resolution-difference-gcc-vs/65706837#comment116172730_65705233), that the rules indeed allow this ambiguity was highlighted in [CWG 1789](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1789) which, afaict, have seen no progress or feedback since 2013.

> #### 1789. Array reference vs array decay in overload resolution
>
> - Section: 12.4.4.3  [over.ics.rank]
> - Status: drafting
> - Submitter: Faisal Vali
> - Date: 2013-10-01
>
> The current rules make an example like
>
> ```
> template<class T, size_t N> void foo(T (&)[N]);
> template<class T> void foo(T *t);
>
> int arr[3]{1, 2, 3};
> foo(arr);
> ```
>
> ambiguous, even though the first is an identity match and the second
> requires an lvalue transformation. Is this desirable?

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me though what the "excluding" refers to. Does it refer to the detection of a subsequence (= we only look at those parts of the sequence which are no Lvalue Transformation to determine whether or not it's a subsequence) or does it refer to the exclusion of this 3.2.1 point?

Comment: Though I'm not sure if it matters: If we ignore lvalue transformation, then identity conversion is not a _proper_ subsequence of array-to-pointer conversion -- it's the same conversion sequence.

Comment: @dyp I agree that the 3.2.1 wording regarding excluding is somewhat unclear. I can’t explain why Clang would choose the rvalue overload of your first example, though.